# Installing Python2.7 on a linux server without root privileges

Tags: linux, bash, python-2.7

I am trying to install python2.7 over given python2.6 on a web server. I am stuck at the last step trying to link new python install over the old one.

The steps I have done:

1. Downloaded and extracted Python 2.7
2. configured with --prefix=$HOME/.local
3. make install

What I don't get is how to link by making changes in .bashrc (and what changes to make). I looked over all the places but most the answers are not generic.

Also, I have to install couple of other lovely python stuff, like pip virtualenv, django, nltk over this. A little help on that would be too great.

Comment: If you don't have root, you can't replace the existing system Python (and you probably can't reconfigure the web server to use the new version). You can run the new version by invoking it explicitly yourself or putting its directory first in your PATH.

Comment: I don't exactly want to replace it.. I just want to use the one I point out to (the newer one) to compile codes. Mostly I wish to run a website with Django (install with pip and under virtual environment). 

How do I put its directory in my path, is actually what I am looking for. I am a noob at this, so it might look silly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, without root privileges you will have to have all the python stuff and your code in your home folder. And also you won't be able to configure your nginx/apache/whatever http server you use. Does not seem like a good idea for production, but for development - sure, why not.

This means you will need to install python in your home folder. You can download and compile, but probably the simplest way to do so is `pyenv` - https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv. Some reading is required to understand its concepts, but it is much simpler than fiddling with manual compiling if you are not sure what you're doing.

Also it kinda replaces virtualenv, but you can still have it if you want. And of course, it all works with your non-root user. There is an installer that doesn't require root either.

Comment: Thanks million. pyenv is awesome! Makes it so simple. However in regards to deployment, it's a shame that I won't be able to configure server which is what I would like to do at the end of the day